# Android Espresso predicates in automated testing?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

Is there any way to achieve predicates similar to in iOS Xcode's `NSPredicate` to wait on certain events in Android Espresso?

For iOS you can call a `expectationForPredicate` and `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` as part of `XCTest`.

I have two similar apps for iOS and Android that I've been tasked with testing. In iOS, I can do the following:

```
  let app = XCUIApplication();
  let condition = app.staticTexts["Text That Displays After Event"]
  let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
  expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: condition, handler: nil)
  waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)

  XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Text That Displays After Event"].exists)
```

In Android the best I can do is register an Idling Resource and wait for a few seconds then check if the event has happened manually.

```
  long waitingTime = 3 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS;
  IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  IdlingResource idlingResource = new ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(waitingTime);
  Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);

  onView(withId(R.id.id_in_next_event)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

  Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
```

I'm sure there has to be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most things can be done with the `Instrumentation#waitForIdleSync()` method. This waits for all UI events to get processed before continuing on.  So say you had a button with the ID `buttonId` that when pressed, it will reveal a View with the ID `hiddenView`.

If you do something like this:

```
private final Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();

@Test
public void checkViewIsRevealed() {
   onView(withId(R.id.buttonId)).perform(click());

   instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();

   onView(withId(R.id.hiddenView)).check(matches(isDisplayed());
}
```

So in this process, performing the "click" would call `View#setVisibility()` on the `hiddenView`.  Then, you wait for idle to ensure that all UI actions go through.  Then check that the new view is displayed.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. It even waits for Volley request which is what I needed.

Comment: @Jack: I would be weary of that. This only waits for all UI operations to finish. Volley is an asynchronous library that is completely separate. I think you're download operations are just really fast (which is good, but it's going to blow up later).

Comment: @DeeV Calling `waitForIdleSync()` is absolutely not required. Espresso does already wait for the app to become idle.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `ViewAction` that waits for a `Matcher<View>` to become true. 
But that is only required if Espresso does not wait on its own. Espresso waits e.g. if the main thread of the application is working or if an `AsyncTask` is running.

The waiting view action could be implemented like:

```
public class WaitForCondition implements ViewAction {
    private static final long IDLING_INTERVAL = 50;
    private final Matcher<View> mCondition;
    private final long mTimeout;

    public WaitForCondition(final Matcher<View> condition, final long timeout) {
        mCondition = condition;
        mTimeout = timeout;
    }

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return isAssignableFrom(View.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return String.format(Locale.US, "Waiting until the condition '%s' will become true (timeout %d ms)", getConditionDescription(), mTimeout);
    }

    private String getConditionDescription() {
        StringDescription description = new StringDescription();
        mCondition.describeTo(description);
        return description.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {

        if (mCondition.matches(view)) {
            return;
        }
        final long timeOut = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeout;

        // Wait for the condition to become true
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= timeOut) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(IDLING_INTERVAL);
            if (mCondition.matches(view)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new PerformException.Builder()
                .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                .withCause(new RuntimeException(String.format(Locale.US,
                        "Condition '%s' did not become true after %d ms of waiting.", getConditionDescription(), mTimeout)))
                .build();
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
onView(withId(R.id.id_in_next_event)).perform(new WaitForCondition(matches(isDisplayed()), 3000));
```